# pandasのリスト要素を加算するときにNaNになることを避ける方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas, numpy

DateFrameの複数の列にそれぞれリストが格納されているときに、リスト内の値を結合して1つのリストを生成したいです。列の値として`NaN`が含まれていない場合は列同時を結合すれば実現できたのですが、`NaN`が含まれる場合に結果が`NaN`となってしまいます。`NaN`を除いて処理を行うにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    "data1" :[["1","2","3"],["1","2","3"]],
    "data2" :[["4","5","6"],["4","5","6"]],
    "data3" :[["7","8","9"],np.nan]
    })
result = df_test["data1"]+ df_test["data2"]+ df_test["data3"]
print(result)

# 結果
# 0    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# 1                            NaN　← [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] としたい
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> df_test.fillna('').applymap(list).sum(axis=1)
0    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
dtype: object
```